# Как менять позиции html блоков c помощью js?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая задача: Имеется пять html блоков, 4 по углам и один в центре, при нажатии на любой из угловых блоков центральный должен занимать позицию нажатого блока а нажатый в свою очередь перемещаться на место центрального.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю как реализовать это на javascript'e.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Я думаю что html и css тут ничем не помогут, ведь дело как раз таки в js, вернее в отсутствии его

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Я помощи прошу, а не халяву ищу

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да ладно, тут кода минут на 5 от силы, а задача кажется очень типичной, может пригодится в будущем кому.

Answer (score 1):

Просто меняйте позиции элементов между собой

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.id == 'center') return;
    let center = document.getElementById('center');
    let cLeft = center.style.left;
    let cTop = center.style.top;
    center.style.left = this.style.left;
    center.style.top = this.style.top;
    this.style.left = cLeft;
    this.style.top = cTop;
    center.removeAttribute('id');
    this.setAttribute('id','center');
  };
}
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="top:0px;left:0px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div style="top:0px;left:100px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="top:50px;left:50px; background-color: blue;" id="center"></div>
<div style="top:100px;left:0px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div style="top:100px;left:100px; background-color: maroon;"></div>
```

Comment: да я просто хотел что бы он просто html добавил - молодца !

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Проект написан на vuejs, просто так не получится добавить html и css =)

Comment: @DenisOed  можно же ... через браузер - он же отдаёт готовый html

Comment: @DenisOed, почему? та же самая разметка и те же самые стили. Причем во vue решение может быть совсем другим, все зависит от исходных данных